# Dependency injection in MVC + Web API, without interfaces of repository in controller constructor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I am going to use SimpleInjector in MVC.5 application with WebAPI.2

Some methods of MVC controllers will create objects of repositories for CRUD operations.
Common approach on the Internet is a using interface of repository in MVC controller, like:

```
public class DashboardController : Controller
{
    private readonly IDashboardRepository _repository;

    public DashboardController (IDashboardRepository repository) {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonData GetInfo()
    {
        return _repository.GetInfo();
    }
...
```

Similar approach is recommended for WebAPI

However I would not like to pass IDashboardRepository into constructor of controller because of such reasons: I am sure that I will never mock implementation of repository. I do not need separate public interface for repository (current code base has no these interfaces and I'll need to change a lot of files to add them).

My repositories look like:

```
public class DashboardFunc : BaseFunc
{
    public DashboardFunc(IApplicationStateProvider sp) :
        base (sp)
    {
    }

    public DashBoardData GetInfo()
    {
        ...
```

I would like to use such code in controllers of MVC:

public class DashboardController : Controller
    {

```
    public DashboardController () {
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonData GetInfo()
    {
        DashboardFunc dashBoard = Global.MvcContainer.GetInstance<DashboardFunc>();
        return Common.ToJson(dashBoard.GetInfo());
    }
```

The same approach I would like for WebAPI controllers. The only difference is
    DashboardFunc dashBoard = Global.WebApiContainer.GetInstance();

Is my modification (not using interface of repository in controller) of standard approach OK? Are there any potential issues that can arise in future that can lead architecture change?

Thank you!

Comment: I'd recommend sticking with the interface approach. You do not need to pass the repository to the controller's constructor; just make the repository inherit from idisposable and use a using statement in your controller methods.

Comment: If you got resharper or any version of VS better then express you can extract inteface from files with one click of mouse. You said that you are afraid of architecture changes but you don't want to make interfaces for repositories what is i think really useful in growing project. You are using IoC in project but you want to handle some object instatination yourself. You have to choose what is better for you but i suggest to stick full IoC implementation - who knows, maybe you will have to change your repo implementation - when that time come, you will thank that you got IoC in project ;)

Answer (score 4):

Prevent falling back on calling `Global.MvcContainer.GetInstance` or any other form of [Service Location
anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/). There are a lot of downsides to this, even if you don't want to test that code. Downsides of using this are (among others):

- You lose the ability for the container to change the given implementation for you; it makes your application less flexible.
- You lose the ability for the container to [diagnose](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/diagnostics.html) the complete object graph for you.
- You lose the ability to [verify the configuration](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/howto.html#verify-configuration) during app start or using an integration test.
- You lose the ability to spot all the class's dependencies just by looking at a single line of code (the constructor).

So even when you don't need that interface, I would advice to still use constructor injection and do the following:

```cs
public class DashboardController : Controller {
    private readonly DashboardFunc dashboard;
    public DashboardController(DashboardFunc dashboard) {
        this.dashboard = dashboard;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonData GetInfo() {
        return Common.ToJson(this.dashBoard.GetInfo());
    }
}
```